# Interpretation of this command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am really new to python and come majorly from programming in R. While studying I came across this snippet of code.

```
xs=[()]
res=[False]*2
if xs:
    res[0]= True
if xs[0]:
    res[1]=True
print(res)
```

Initially I thought that this is a way to initialize an empty array. However when I run the same snippet replacing the initialize part with an empty list, it gives me an error.

```
xs=list()
res=[False]*2
if xs:
    res[0]= True
if xs[0]:
    res[1]=True
print(res)
```

Can someone please help me understand the difference between these 2 codes. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: here xs is an empty list and your are trying to call xs[0], That is not possible thus it shows an error.. In the initial case, xs was a list with an empty tuple as element.

Comment: What is the difference between xs=list() and xs=[()]. Both of them are supposed to initialize empty arrays, but one of them is throws an error while the other one does not.

Comment: yeah but  the index zero has the object which is en empty tuple so something is there

Comment: In both cases, just print `len(xs)` and you'll see the problem. You can't index empty sequences (at least not like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base of the problem is the two list definitions, consider the code:

```
xs1 = [()]   # create a list with a single element, which is an empty tuple
xs2 = list() # create an empty list
```

xs has one element (an empty list) in your first code block, so it works. In the second code block xs is truly empty (has zero elements) so the code fails, since xs[0] does not exist.

Comment: So does this mean that I can access any hypothetical index of a tuple, even though it isn't initialized?

Comment: @Mohit - no it's the opposite, you can only access it when it exists.  The explanation is confusing because the first element of xs (i.e. xs[0]) is itself an empty element.  xs[0] => ()

Answer (score 0):

in the first

```
xs=[()] <---------
```

your xs look like this

```
xs[0] = ()
```

in the second

```
xs = list()
```

means

```
xs = []
```

so

```
xs[0] # does not xsist
```